# Necessary to declare local variables in a loop?

Tags: ecmascript-6, traceur

I'm finding the following works fine:

```
while ((_next = itr.next()) && !_next.done) {
    ...
}
```

and without any prior declaration of `_next`, traceur in fact throws an unexpected key word error if I do declare the variable `while ((let _next = itr.next()) ...`.

Is this ECMAScript 6?

Comment: Btw, you're missing a closing `)`

Comment: Why are you manually handling the results from the iterator, instead of just doing `for (x of itr)`?

Comment: A number of reasons you might want to do this, one example, you need to know if the iterator is empty or not before processing a value returned from the iterator - read ahead loops.

Comment: Take an iterator returning numbers, to return the lowest value in the iterator, _if_ it is not an empty iterator, `wu(itr).reduce( ( m, x ) => Math.min( m, x ), first_iteration_value)` I'm not interested in the minimum value of no values (which javascript returns as infinity btw).  More a question of readability I think than anything, a question of style and maintainability.  You would still have to test the returned value following if not before.

Comment: Aonther case, I'm testing transcompiled ES6 JS from ES5 JS (if there is a test framework that runs ES6 tests I'm not aware of it yet).

Comment: If I have an iterator returning infinite numbers the code however will only be processing numbers below a given value, a `for` loop could be used with `break` test at the top of the loop, or a read ahead `while` loop (maybe appropriate if processing initial values differently, but otherwise an extra line of code), or tail recursion (for code reuse reasons, the same recursive function may be called else where).

Comment: Apart from the vanilla `for ( ... of ...)` IMHO what will probably prove the most common technique after this will be to initialise loop variables with an `_itr.next()` call and then to loop through the remaining iterator values with `for (.. of ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `while ((let _next = itr.next()) ...`Is this ECMAScript 6?

No. `while` statements must contain expressions, not variable declarations. And variable declarations inside the grouping operator are invalid anyway. This hasn't changed since ES5.
Use

```
var _next;
while ((_next = itr.next()) && !_next.done) {
    …
}
```

or just

```
for (let … of itr) {
    …
}
```